# Como passar um arquivo .sh como parâmetro para um código em C?

Tags: c, shell-script

Preciso passar como parâmetro para um programa em C um arquivo com extensão .sh .Já tentei da seguinte forma e o valor que é lido do arquivo está errado: ./programa ./arquivo.sh

Como faço para conseguir passar este argumento? É preciso adicionar algo ao make?
Obrigada

Comment: Ola bkira, o que vc quer é passar parâmetros para o executável por linha de comando?

Comment: A sintaxe está incorreta, tente assim: ./programa < arquivo.sh

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar os argumentos `argc` e `argv[]` da função `main`.
Os parâmetros `argc` e `argv` dão ao programador acesso à linha de comando com a qual o programa foi chamado.

O `argc` (argument count) é um inteiro e possui o número de argumentos com os quais a função `main()` foi chamada na linha de comando.

O `argv` (argument values) é um vetor de strings. Cada string deste vetor é um dos parâmetros da linha de comando. É para saber quantos elementos temos em `argv` que temos `argc`.

Veja um exemplo de um programa que recebe como parâmetro o caminho de um **arquivo.h** qualquer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char *caminho_arquivo;

    if (argc == 2) /*Quantidade de parâmetros.*/
        caminho_arquivo = argv[1];

    printf("\nCaminho: %s\n\n", caminho_arquivo);

    return 0;
}
```

Entrada, o programa é executado com dois parâmetros, são eles, *nome do executável* e *caminho do arquivo.h*: `./exemplo1 /home/user\ joao/arquivo.h`

Saida: `/home/user joao/arquivo.h`

Se você estiver usando linux e caso o caminho do seu arquivo.h contenha espaços em brancos, você deve formata-los usando o `\` por exemplo: `/home/user joao/arquivo.h` deverar ficar assim `/home/user\ joao/arquivo.h`.

[Fonte](http://linguagemc.com.br/argumentos-em-linha-de-comando/).

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de sua pergunta ter ficado um pouco vaga (devido a falta de exemplo de código), aqui vai uma possível solução.

Programas na linguagem C possuem como argumento para seu método principal *main* a quantidade de argumentos recebidos e um array com estes argumentos.

Segue um exemplo de código onde é possível acessar os argumentos recebidos pela linha de comando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    printf( argv[1] );
}
```

Observação: o argumento de índice zero é sempre o nome do próprio programa em C.