# Como usar os parâmetros na linha de comando

Tags: c

estou com dúvida quanto ao uso dos parâmetros na linha de comando, tipo, uma das funcionalidades do trabalho da universidade é tratar alguns argumentos por linha de comando, por exemplo:

./programa -e -i arquivo.txt arquivoDestino.txt

Não sei como usar argumentos maiores, exceto as opções "-e" por exemplo, gostaria de saber como consigo chamar um arquivo texto na linha de comando ou algo do tipo

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94900/27190) e veja se resolve.

Answer (score 2):

tem muitas formas de fazer isso, vocẽ pode checar cada argumento passado e quando determinado argumento for aquele especifico basta voce pegar o proximo paramentro e depois pular ele para não ser checado. um exemplo seria se o seu programa faz uma checagem da idade passada no paramentro -i, quando o programa achar o -i ele pega o proximo argumento depois do -i que é a idade e depois pula o proximo argumento no contador para nao checar o valor da idade passado como argumento

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int contParam, idade = 0;
   //corre cada paramatro passado
   for(contParam = 0; contParam < argc; contParam++){
      //se o parametro passado for -i ele executa isso
      if(!strcmp(argv[contParam],"-i")){
         //armazena na variavel local o valor passado
         //que seria o paramatro + 1
         idade = atoi(argv[contParam + 1]); //pega o proximo valor
         contParam += 1; //checa outro parametro desconsiderando
                         //o proprio valor como parametro
      }
   }

   printf("idade = %d \n",idade);
}
```

no exemplo anterior se voce passar para o programa -i 10 ele vai exibir a idade 10

```
kodo.exe -i 10
```

se voce passar para ele outro valor antes do menos -i, o resultado sera o mesmo devido o programa pegar o valor depois do -i

```
kodo.exe 50 -i 10
```

o mesmo vale caso o valor seja passado depois do valor do -i

```
kodo.exe 50 -i 10 80
```

claro se voce passar outro -i vai sobrescrever o valor na variavel, o bom que isso permite passar parametros para o seu programa sem uma ordem especifica tambem

```
kodo.exe 50 -i 10 80 -i 30
```

outro exemplo agora passando o nome no parametro -n, idade no -i e a data no -d

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int contParam, idade = 0;
   char nome[100] = "", data[20] = "";

   for(contParam = 0; contParam < argc; contParam++){
      if(!strcmp(argv[contParam],"-i")){
         idade = atoi(argv[contParam + 1]);
         contParam += 1;
      }

      else if(!strcmp(argv[contParam],"-n")){
         strncpy(nome,argv[contParam + 1],100);
         contParam += 1;
      }

      else if(!strcmp(argv[contParam],"-d")){
         strncpy(data,argv[contParam + 1],20);
         contParam += 1;
      }
   }

   printf("nome = %s \n",nome);
   printf("idade = %d \n",idade);
   printf("data = %s \n",data);
}
```

o comando no terminal seria

```
kodo.exe -d "25/06/2017" -n "kodo no kami" -i 20
```

a saida no terminal ficaria assim

```
nome = kodo no kami 
idade = 20 
data = 25/06/2017
```

Comment: Ótima resposta; talvez só conviesse adicionar que, se o programa determinar que um determinado elemento do vetor `argv` deve ser interpretado como um nome de arquivo, ele pode ser aberto normalmente usando a API de leitura de arquivo (`FILE * stream = fopen(argv[n], "r");` ou `int fd = open(argv[n], O_READ);`)

Comment: Aliás, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Espero que tenha oportunidade de contribuir mais...

Answer (score 1):

Faça uso dos argumentos `argv` e `argc`.

`argv` e `argc` são como os argumentos da linha de comando são passados para `main()` em C e C++.

`argc` será o número de *strings* apontadas por `argv`. Na prática, isto será 1 mais o número de argumentos, já que praticamente todas as implementações adicionam o nome do programa para o *array*.

As variáveis são denominadas `argc` (*argument count*) e `argv` (*argument vector*) por convenção, mas podem receber qualquer identificador válido: `int main(int num_args, char ** arg_strings)` é igualmente válido.

Eles também podem ser omitidos inteiramente, produzindo `int main()`, se você não pretende processar argumentos de linha de comando.

Tente o código a seguir:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Existem %d argumentos\n", argc);

  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    printf("Argumento [%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Rodando com `./programa -e -i arquivo.txt arquivoDestino.txt` a saída será

```
Existem 5 argumentos
Argumento [0]: ./programa
Argumento [1]: -e
Argumento [2]: -i
Argumento [3]: arquivo.txt
Argumento [4]: arquivoDestino.txt
```

Comment: Não é que _"...praticamente todas as implementações adicionam o nome do programa para o_ array _"_; o [padrão](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf#page=24) manda que se o valor de `argc` for maior que zero, `argc[0]` tem que representar o nome do programa.